# How to initialize form field value?

Tags: angularjs, forms

Is there a way to initialize the following form fields so the Angular code doesn't display "NaN" when the form is loaded?  Having the value start at zero would be nice.

```
<input type="text" id="field1" value="0"/>
<input type="text" id="field2" value="0"/>
<br />

Total {{field1*50--field2}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cn0tCJlclIMXivli1is0?p=preview

Comment: Honestly... just use Angular as intended - use a controller and initialize all the values there. You *could* use `ng-init`, but really, the learning curve of Angular is not worth it unless you use it as intended to its full power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ng-init` directive. Here's the stuff copied from your plunker that works with it. But you should use this with caution, here's an excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

`The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    testing
    <input type="text" id="field1" ng-model="field1" ng-init="field1 = 0"/>
    <input type="text" id="field2" ng-model="field2" ng-init="field2 = 0"/>
    <br />

    Total {{field1*50--field2}}
    
  </body>

</html>
```

So really, you should do this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      function init() {
        $scope.field1 = 0;
        $scope.field2 = 0;
      }
      init();
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    testing
    <input type="text" id="field1" ng-model="field1" />
    <input type="text" id="field2" ng-model="field2" />
    <br />Total {{ field1 * 50 - -field2}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add a `controller` to your HTML and assign a `ng-model` to your `<input>` fields and intialize it with some values in the controller instead of using `value` in `<input>`.

That's enough to have a default value for the fields

Here is the working plunker of your code,

http://embed.plnkr.co/Ssk1bP6LWq9YgAIDYaEk/preview

Hope this helps!!!!